# PyCharm: How to toggle auto-scroll in source window?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I step throught the source code during debugging, the source window auto-scrolls keeping the current line in the middle. Is there a way to turn this off or customize? It's annoying to see source "hickup" on every step.